# gulp-jslint doesn't include error description in output, says "undefined : undefined" instead

Tags: node.js, gulp, jslint

I'm running gulp-jslint and it correctly flags errors, but doesn't include the description of the errors in the output.

Here's gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jslint = require('gulp-jslint');

gulp.task('default', ['jslint-server']);

gulp.task('jslint-server', function () {
    return gulp.src([ // some example files
                    'scripts/*.js',
                    'web-server.js'
                ])
            .pipe(jslint({ node:true, bitwise:true }))
            .pipe(jslint.reporter( 'stylish' ));
});
```

And here's the output:

```
 ✓ config.js
 ✖ ConfigController.js
   ✖ 6:undefined: undefined
   ✖ 8:undefined: undefined
 ✓ FeaturesController.js
 ✓ web-server.js
```

It has correctly flagged two errors.  However, I would expect to see a description of the errors where it says, "undefined : undefined".

Any advice on getting rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `gulp-jslint`.

Something similar was reported for the `'default'` reporter in [issue #33](https://github.com/karimsa/gulp-jslint/issues/33). The problem was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/karimsa/gulp-jslint/commit/a9c9e625d1fbec0113e5386e8772dbf5595b5ce0) for the v1.0.2 release.

However it seems the author of `gulp-jslint` forgot to apply the same fix to the `'stylish'` reporter that you are using.

The best thing would be to report this issue on GitHub and include a link to this question.

Until this is fixed you can use the following workaround:

```
gulp.task('jslint-server', function () {
  return gulp.src([ 
    'scripts/*.js',
    'web-server.js'
  ])
  .pipe(jslint({ node:true, bitwise:true }))
  //--- workaround ---
  .on('data', function(file) {
    file.jslint.errors.forEach(function(err) {
      err.column = err.column || err.character;
      err.message = err.message || err.reason;
    });
  })
  //------------------
 .pipe(jslint.reporter( 'stylish' ));
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll report on github as you suggested.  Interestingly, I tried the default reporter and got the same result.

Comment: The v1.0.2 release wasn't published to npm (it's still v1.0.1 there). So unless you installed directly from GitHub you don't have the `'default'` reporter fix yet.

Comment: EDIT:  I was running 1.0.1, as 1.0.2 is not yet the current release, so not seeing the fix makes sense.